# Pass jquery input value to url?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am able to pass plain text to my api's url as follows:

`var bus = $('.location').text();
$.getJSON('http://apiofsite'+bus+'apiofsitecontinued.com'), function(){
do something});`

Now I want to be able to do the same thing, but using the input field instead of printed HTML. Something like so:

`<input id="stuff" type="input" />`

So ideally my JS would be like so.

`var sang = $('#stuff').val();
$.getJSON('http://apiofsomewebsite'+sang+'apiofsomewebsitecontinued.com'), function(){
do something});`

I don't believe that the URL is reading my input, as it returns empty.

Comment: Is this code within a function that runs `onClick`, after the user has entered a term?

Comment: it's run by `$(document).on('click', '#somerandomdiv', function(){myproblemhere});` after user has entered into `#stuff`

Comment: Can you provide a working example through SO's embedded code, or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Figured it out. Since I can't delete this question I'll just share my answer here. Basically, when transferring input values into an API url, be sure to format your string. So, for instance, in my example, you should add `var sang = $('#stuff').val().replace(/\s+/g, '')` to remove spaces and extra characters that should not be in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual ajax call.
Try this:

```
var url = 'http://apiofsomewebsite'+ $('#stuff').val() + 'apiofsomewebsitecontinued.com';
console.log(url);
//$.getJSON(url, function() {...});
```

If the url is not the one you expected, check to see you are placing the code in the right event (i.e. the field's `change` event, a button's `click` event, or the form's submission etc.) when the input value is available.